# Jquery Contains:value, find text in table and return the td next to it

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm looking for is a way to find a text on a table and report back the td next to that field. The user will have to input the text of course.
 For some reason this line is not working for me

```
 $("tr td:contains('" + test + "')")
```

Here is the code (see also demo below):

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr><td class='eClass'> 4</td><td >test</td></tr>
    <tr><td>blah test blah</td><td class='eClass'>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>blah blah test</td><td class='eClass'>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test blah blah</td><td class='eClass'>4</td></tr>
</table>
<input class="from" value=""></input>


<p class='total'></p>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(".from").keyup(function () {
    var test = $(".from").val()

    $("tr td:contains('" + test + "')").each(function () {
        var a = $(this).siblings('td.eClass').html()
        $(".total").html(a)

    });

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/A2Htn/4/

*
If I type 4 in the input field I should get test. If I press 3 I should get blah test blah
*

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you log the contains object to the console and see what it said?

Comment: Yep. I get something like this: TypeError: `$(...) is null`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var a=$(this).html()
```

instead of

```
var a = $(this).siblings('td.eClass').html()
```

Comment: Now I'm jus getting back the number I typed.I want to get back the text that is in the cell on the same row

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself (well help from a friend)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QB79y/

There should be an if within the .each in order for each to return the correct result and not just the last one (of course)

```
$( ".from" ).keyup(function() { 
    var  test = $(".from").val();
    $(".tabledata td").each(function(){
      if ($(this).html()==test){
        var a=$(this).siblings('td').html()
        $(".total").html(a) 
          };
    });

});
```